# make error while installng aircrack ng

Tags: wireless, compiling

when i type make

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/m7moudl3i/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc2/src'
gcc -g -W -Wall -O3 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REVISION=0  -DCONFIG_LIBNL30 -DCONFIG_LIBNL -I/usr/include/libnl3  -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-array-bounds -Iinclude   -c -o aircrack-ng.o aircrack-ng.c
In file included from aircrack-ng.c:65:0:
crypto.h:42:26: fatal error: openssl/hmac.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/hmac.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'aircrack-ng.o' failed
make[1]: *** [aircrack-ng.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/m7moudl3i/aircrack-ng-1.2-rc2/src'
Makefile:25: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [requirements](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_aircrack) for building `aircrack-ng` from source on linux, you can see that it needs `libssl-dev`. So install it using:

> `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`